# Event object is null with Firefox

Tags: jsviews

I use jsViews to create a small form.

In the template I defined some buttons I bound to a custom handler.

Within the handler, I want to play with the `event` object (especially, I want to prevent the default button behavior which is to submit the outer `<form>`.

This works as expected with all browsers I tested except Firefox. the event object is `undefined` with Firefox. All other browsers have a `MouseEvent` object defined.

How to fix it using FF ?

Here is a small repro:

```js
(function($) {
  var dataVm = {
    value: 42
  };

  var handlers = {
    changeValue: function(valueToAdd) {
      $.observable(dataVm).setProperty("value", dataVm.value + valueToAdd);
      console.log(event); // Should not be undefined
    }
  };

  $.templates("#mainTemplate").link("#container", dataVm, handlers);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>
<script id="mainTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <input data-link="value" />
  <button data-link="{on ~changeValue 1}">+1</button>
  <button data-link="{on ~changeValue (-1)}">-1</button>
</script>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

PS: I use jQuery 1.12.4 and jsViews 0.9.90

Comment: Where is the event argument from? I don't see where it was from.

Comment: @Anson: it is the standard object that contains event related properties

Comment: Try **console.log(arguments)** and you'll see **arguments[1]** might be the event object you are looking for.

Comment: @anson: please post an answer, as it seems to solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In callback functions, you may inspect **arguments** and see what you need. In this case, we can try this inside **changeValue** callback:

```
(function($) {
  var dataVm = {
    value: 42
  };

  var handlers = {
    changeValue: function(valueToAdd) {
      $.observable(dataVm).setProperty("value", dataVm.value + valueToAdd);
      console.log(arguments); // check what actual arguments are
    }
  };

  $.templates("#mainTemplate").link("#container", dataVm, handlers);
})(jQuery);
```

And, you are now able to reach **arguments[1]** as **event** to execute **preventDefault** of that.

```
(function($) {
  var dataVm = {
    value: 42
  };

  var handlers = {
    changeValue: function(valueToAdd) {
      var theEvent = arguments[1];
      $.observable(dataVm).setProperty("value", dataVm.value + valueToAdd);
      console.log(arguments); // check what actual arguments are
      theEvent.preventDefault(); // execute preventDefault from it
    }
  };

  $.templates("#mainTemplate").link("#container", dataVm, handlers);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works as expected. As a side note, I found more readable to name the event argument in the function signature : `changeValue: function(valueToAdd, evt) { ... evt.XXX(); ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation for `{on}`](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvontag).

The arguments passed to the {on} event handler are explained here:
http://www.jsviews.com/#link-events, in the section **The signature of the event handler function**, where it says:

> If the `{on}` binding is:
>
> ```
> {^{on 'click' myHandler param1 param2 data=myData}}
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> data-link="{on 'click' myHandler param1 param2 data=myData}"
> ```
>
> then the `myHandler` function should have the signature:
>
> ```
> function myHandler(param1, param2, ev, eventArgs) { ... }
> ```
>
> where `ev` is the jQuery event object and `eventArgs` is the JsViews event
>   object